# Performance change of using % in a SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm writing SQL queries and something utilize the % sign in the query. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state='NewYork%'
```

My question is how does using the % in variable positions affect performance in MySQL? How does it work with index?

```
Ex 1: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state='NewYork%'

Ex 2: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state='%NewYork'

Ex 3: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state='%NewYork%'

Ex 4: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state='New%York'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'LIKE' rather than '='?

Comment: do you mean select * from table where state like '%New York%'?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use the `LIKE` operator, it is most likely that the `%` would be considered the same as any other character.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can use an index if your query looks like `foo LIKE 'abc%'` or `foo LIKE 'abc%def%'`. It can use the index for any portion or the string before the first wildcard. If you need to match a word anywhere within a string, you might want to consider using `FULLTEXT` indexes instead.

More detail on indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

Full text search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Check out some performance tips here: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips

Comment: `LIKE 'abc%'` is indeed an index seek.  But `LIKE 'abc%def%'` will at best be a range seek followed by a scan.  Thus the performance is inherently related to the distribution of the data values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean LIKE,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state like 'NewYork%'

Ex 1: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state like 'NewYork%'

Ex 2: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state like '%NewYork'

Ex 3: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state like '%NewYork%'

Ex 4: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state like 'New%York'
```

The best way is having fulltext index on that field if your engine is MyIsam, Aria or Innodb (mysql 5.6+), now talkin about the `'%'` (wildcard) the best performance in your 4 example will be in:

```
Ex 1: SELECT * FROM TABLE A where state like 'NewYork%'
```

because Mysql have a word listing and it will be faster identify words that start with.... than words that end or have ....